# AWS spot price history coming empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, price

I got AWS CLI tools and account on AWS. I ran the command aws configure and set the AWS Access key, AWS secret key, region and output format. Now when I am running the command

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history --instance-type m1.xlarge --product-description "Linux/Unix"
```

I get the output empty

```
{
    "SpotPriceHistory": []
}
```

I have tried it with multiple instance types, giving start time and end time etc.
Please can someone help me on this.

Comment: Are you using a IAM user? Does the user has the proper policy?

Comment: Yes. I think I have the proper permissions because it had worked once for m1.xlarge after which now for any instance type I am getting an empty json.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your account supports launching an [ec2-classic instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html) ?

If you created your account after 2013-12-04, it supports EC2-VPC only and to retrieve the information you will need to specify that you want ec2 instances from VPC

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history --product-description "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)" --instance-type m1.xlarge
```

Comment: I don't want EC2-VPC. I want information for "Linux/Unix".

Comment: if your account has been created after 2013-12-04, you have no choice it **must** be ec2-VPC and AWS will create a default VPC for you. run your command with `--product-description "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)"` and you will see it retrieves the unix/linux instance